# PhoneGap upload Image to server on form submit

Tags: image, cordova, upload

I am facing problem here as in phonegap image is uploaded to the server once u select a picture.I don't want to upload image before submitting form. Image is uploaded automatically to server which is something i don't want.I want to upload image with the form, where form contains many more fields which is required to send along with image.  What are the possible ways to submit with form?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
// Do cool things here...
    }

    function getImage() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('get picture failed');
},{
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});}
    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="regform">
<button onclick="getImage();">select Avatar<button>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
<input type="text" id="workPlace" name="workPlace" class="" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create two functions you can call separately. One function for just getting the image, and another function to upload the image.

You can do something like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Submit form</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }


    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

        // Show the selected image
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = imageURI;
    }


    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    function uploadPhoto() {

        //selected photo URI is in the src attribute (we set this on getPhoto)
        var imageURI = document.getElementById('smallImage').getAttribute("src");
        if (!imageURI) {
            alert('Please select an image first.');
            return;
        }

        //set upload options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

        options.params = {
            firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
            lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
            workplace: document.getElementById("workplace").value
        }

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        //alert("Response =" + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="regform">
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Select Photo:</button><br>
        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />

        First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
        Work Place: <input type="text" id="workplace" name="workPlace"><br>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPhoto();">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ! I am using your code and does work fine with taking image and uploading to server! But it does not work with displaying the image, though it does assigns the path to image.src but cannot display the image :(

Comment: Can it be that I am missing some plugin? I have posted the complete question over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125080/appgyver-cordova-not-able-to-display-captured-image

Comment: I looked at your post on the link. Your modified code is trying to show the image in the uploadPhoto function which is never called untill you upload the photo. Put it in a function like onPhotoURISuccess in the example. Look at the getPhoto function in the example. It's the first parameter in navigator.camera.getPicture(YourFunctionNameHereThatDisplayTheImage, ...)

Comment: My uploadPhoto function is the same as your onPhotoURISuccess and I if you look at it, it is the very first function :)

Comment: I don't know why but I am not able to select image with above code, but if i remove form tag from body, Image gets retrieved. Please help?

Comment: If I put the <button> inside the <form> then the app reloads when clicking the button, and so does not save the image. If I put <button> outside <form> it does upload the image.

Answer (score 1):

You're already sending custom fields in your example.

```
var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;
```

Just populate `params` with your form fields.

Comment: what if form fields are empty..params is just static values. i want to send image on form submit which is not happening.

Comment: Fill params with your form contents before sending... is you use jQuery something like `params.name = $('#inputName').val()` and so on..

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but select avatar button is the first element in the form.what u r saying is to fill up the fields and then upload image with input fields parameter. I want to upload image on submit button of the form. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user3420072 you can try to manually process what and how to submit by  using "onSubmit" in the form. Also you can try doubtful trick: add to form invisible input with it's value equals to image base64 string

Comment: @Regent worth noting that on some devices (notably ipad mini and cheap androids) you can incur in memory errors using base64 images from `camera`.

Comment: @user3420072 we're saying the same thing. You have simply to use that function to upload the image on the `click` event of your submit button. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Paolo Casciello yes, but i still hope that i will not face this problem in my current project... At least i send info and image's base64 string as one post request - it simplifies the process of sending and receiving data.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem, but I have done using two server side calls on one click. In this, in first call submit data and get its id in callback using JSON then upload image using this id. On server side updated data and image using this id.

```
$('#btn_Submit').on('click',function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if(event.handled !== true)
   {
      var ajax_call = serviceURL; 
      var str = $('#frm_id').serialize();                 
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajax_call,
      data: str,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response){
              //console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
        $.each(response, function(key, value) { 
              if(value.Id){                               
                   if($('#vImage').attr('src')){
                         var imagefile = imageURI; 
                          $('#vImage').attr('src', imagefile);
                        /* Image Upload Start */
                          var ft = new FileTransfer();                     
                        var options = new FileUploadOptions();                      
                        options.fileKey="vImage";                      
                        options.fileName=imagefile.substr(imagefile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";  
                        var params = new Object();
                        params.value1 = "test";
                        params.value2 = "param";                       
                        options.params = params;
                        options.chunkedMode = false;                       
                        ft.upload(imagefile, your_service_url+'&Id='+Id+'&mode=upload', win, fail, options); 
                      /* Image Upload End */
                   }      
               }

             }); 
          }
     }).done(function() {
          $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();              
     })

   event.handled = true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

**On server side using PHP**

```
if($_GET['type'] != "upload"){
  // Add insert logic code
}else if($_GET['type'] == "upload"){
  // Add  logic for image 
  if(!empty($_FILES['vImage']) ){ 
    // Copy image code and update data  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get these plugins to upload a file with the other answers.

The problem seemed to stem from the [FileTransfer plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html#upload), which states:

> fileURL: Filesystem URL representing the file on the device or a data URI.

But that **did not** appear to work properly for me.  Instead I needed to use the [File plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) to create a temporary file using the data uri to get me a blob object: in their example, `writeFile` is a function which takes a `fileEntry` (returned by `createFile`) and `dataObj` (blob).  Once the file is written, its path can be retrieved and passed to the FileTransfer instance.  Seems like an awful lot of work, but at least it's now uploading.