# Uploading Images using phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to phonegap and facing lot of troubles in uploading images to the server.

I am uploading a single image to the server both by browsing and using a camera.
I want to upload multiple images by using camera and browsing into the gallery at the same time.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23282229/1682392 maybe it can help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Submit form</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }


    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

        // Show the selected image
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = imageURI;
    }


    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    function uploadPhoto() {

        //selected photo URI is in the src attribute (we set this on getPhoto)
        var imageURI = document.getElementById('smallImage').getAttribute("src");
        if (!imageURI) {
            alert('Please select an image first.');
            return;
        }

        //set upload options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

        options.params = {
            firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
            lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
            workplace: document.getElementById("workplace").value
        }

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        //alert("Response =" + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="regform">
        <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Select Photo:</button><br>
        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />

        First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
        Work Place: <input type="text" id="workplace" name="workPlace"><br>
        <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="uploadPhoto();">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And if you want to get the image from library instead of using the camera use the function described in the answer getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY); 
However for selecting various images you are gonna face some troubles as you can see here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1215

You will have to write a custom plugin for that or find if someone already made one  http://plugins.cordova.io/