# Appgyver/Cordova: Not able to display captured image

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, steroids

I am able to successfully grab the image from photo library as well as camera and able to sent them to server using [*FileTransfer plugin*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer), for saving them. But the only piece of code that is not working for is displaying the Image :( When I alert the *ImageURI*, it gives me the below path:

```
file://storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.apgyver.freshandroid/cache/.Pic.jpg
```

I am not sure if I am missing any plugin or maybe some piece of code?

```
function getImage() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
    alert('get picture failed');
},{
    quality: 50, 
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
    );

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

    //alert(imageURI); return false;
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, url, win, fail, options);
}
```

It does assign the path to `src` but image cannot be displayed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing the *img* element with id *myImage* which has *width* and *height* set to some value so that it is visible, and is given `display: block`. Your code follows strictly the code from the examples of the Camera plugin usage and since it goes correctly to the server you should have all the plugins & permissions needed.

Comment: I already have set inline styling of display: block as well as width and height but still not able to display the image :(

Comment: @atif: I'm sorry, but without seeing the actual case, it is really hard to see if their are any other problems. You could send me your _apk_ which has `android:debuggable=“true”` in its config. This way I could run it with debugger to see the actual problem. My email is on my profile if you wish to do so.

Comment: I have the image element with id "myImage" and also I tried this code as well: var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.style.display = 'block';
        image.src = imageURI;